# KeyboardAvoidingView not working in a Modal (React-Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-native-modalize` for my modals. And in my modal I have an input and I want to place the modal above the keyboard when I select the input.

I have tried `KeyboardAvoidingView` but it's not working properly.
Here are the solutions I tried.

1)

```
<Modalize ref={modalizeRef} adjustToContentHeight={true}>
   <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined}
    >
```

and changing to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

This working perfectly for the modal, but for other `keyboardAvoidingViews` where I have for example `behaviour='position'` it's breaking.

2.
I also tried this prop, but when the keyboard is closed the Modal keeps a whitespace instead of the keyboard
`keyboardVerticalOffset={500}`

Is there a solution I can apply only for Modal, not all the project ?

Thanks in advance, your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

React-native-modalize has built in properties for avoiding keyboard like keyboardAvoidingBehavior, keyboardAvoidingOffset. You don't need KeyboardAvoidingView. Did you try with them?
Link: https://jeremybarbet.github.io/react-native-modalize/#/PROPS?id=keyboardavoidingbehavior